# ma langue passe / m’a-langue passe / t’a-chaussure glisse

Tags: jeux-de-mots

Bonjour,

Dans *[Zéro coup de feu](https://schabrieres.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/gherasim-luca-zero-coup-de-feu-1991/)* de Ghérasim Luca :

> ta bouche glisse sans chaussure gauche
>
> ni chaussure droite
>
> ma langue passe
>
> m’a-langue passe
>
> t’a-chaussure glisse
>
> m’a-langue passe

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre les jeux de mots ici.

Quel est le sens du jeu entre *ma langue passe*, *m'a-langue passe* et *t'a-chaussure glisse* ?

Comment: Je me jette à l'eau. Si la lettre "a" ici veut dire sans, c'est comme si les limites de la personne se dissolvent. Mais, bon, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une science exacte ici.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne crois pas qu'on puis facilement trouver une signification. *M'a* est probablement une construction avec le verbe avoir simplement mise en parallèle avec le possessif *ma* pour faire ressortir leur équivalence phonétique.

Voici qui décrit bien le style de Ghérasim Luca :

> *En ce sens, on ne trouve pas de syllepses : l’accent est porté non sur le signifié mais sur le signifiant. C’est l’assonance qui est recherchée, particulièrement à partir de l’homophonie, en une sorte d’apophonie généralisée où domine la paronomase.*
> Pierrick Briand, *[L'insistance sur l'homophonie chez Gherasim Luca : création poétique et association libre](https://www.cairn.info/revue-le-coq-heron-2007-2-page-59.htm)*, 2007

Comment: Merci. Qu'est ce que ça veut dire "mise en parallèle avec le possessif" ?

Comment: La forme verbale *m'a* et le déterminant possessif *ma* sont mis en parallèle, l'auteur montre leur homophonie.